# how to stop using export command

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, gdb

every time I run gdb I have to type `export SHELL=/bin/bash` or gdb would return `exit with code 127`
my question how to make this command run every time automatically without need to re type it because it is annoying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
export SHELL=/bin/bash
```

to your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: well there is no such file I tried `vim ~/.bashrc` and `vim  .bashrc` but I got empty file !!

Comment: That's OK. All that means is that this is the first time you have customized your shell.